# Do slicers in a Power BI report affect dashboards built off that report?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I have a report that encompasses information for 19 different business units.  I know I can't slice the data on a dashboard, but if I use a slicer in the report to look at Unit A, and then pin a visual, will the slicer selection pass through to the dashboard?  If someone else comes through and slices the report to look at Unit B, will the dashboard stay at Unit A?  My google-fu has been lacking in determining how dashboards interact with the underlying report.

Answer (score 0):

No, slicers cannot drill down. They are like one filter at a time logic. this will help you get more detail

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers